# BTS7960 current limit

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, current-limiting, motordriver

I want to ask about current limit at BTS7960. I'm not clearly understand when read the bts7960 datasheet. I have using 24 V 20A power supply connect to BTS7960 then connect to 24 V 14 A DC motor. When running the motor, after apply some load, DC motor stop running. Maybe BTS7960 cut the supply to DC motor when detected current from DC motor increase. The question is has BTS7960 can set current limit? Or any suggestion to solve this error? Really hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem, ideally with a schematic of your setup, pictures of components, and some measurements.  As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet you do not understand. Links to any other data sheets for the PSU and motor would also help us answer.

Comment: _"Maybe BTS7960 cut the supply to DC motor when detected current from DC motor increase."_ Measure and find out.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you have to look for with power electronics is not the peak handling current (43A) but heat dissipation. This can be tricky, based on the layout of the PCB as well as things like the gate driving voltage (for MOSFETS) and the switching time for transitions between on and off (like with a PWM circuit).

The available copper area on a PCB (or a heat sink) for the motor driver decreases your thermal resistance to air, which increases the power handling capability of the circuit. For PWM circuits, faster switch transition speed decreases the average switch resistance, which decreases power losses at the expense of higher RF emission.

A rough estimate can be given as follows: since your desired output voltage is basically the same as your input voltage, the duty cycle of the switch is 100%. From the datasheet, the maximum on-state resistance of the power switch is 18m ohm. The maximum junction temperature is listed as 150C. An estimate of thermal resistance from junction to ambient (Air) is given as 35C/W. So, we can say that your power dissipation is P = I^2*R = 14^2 * 0.018 = 3.53W. Then your temperature rise above ambient is T = R_JA*P = 35C/W*3.53W = 123.55C. If you add this to ambient temperature of ~25C, you get about 148.55C, which is within some error of the maximum temperature of the device. So your device is probably going into a thermal shutdown mode.

So your options are to increase the heatsink area of the device. If you have BTS7960P, you have to add a heatsink to the tab of the driver. If you have BTS7960B, you have to increase the copper area. Otherwise, look for another motor driver or another motor.

Datasheet:
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS7960-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b43945006d5d&ack=t